# Personalized login button generated by Google

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, google-signin

Google has a [code generator](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/tools/configurator) that generates a [personalized login with Google button](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/personalized-button). A sample of the code generated by the generator is as the following.

```
<div id="g_id_onload"
     data-client_id="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
     data-context="signin"
     data-ux_mode="popup"
     data-callback="localhost:1234/callback"
     data-nonce=""
     data-auto_prompt="false">
</div>

<div class="g_id_signin"
     data-type="standard"
     data-shape="rectangular"
     data-theme="outline"
     data-text="signin_with"
     data-size="large"
     data-logo_alignment="left">
</div>
```

I have a few questions to understand this button better.

- Why is there no client secret?
- This button gets an ID token, but what about a refresh and access token? How could you refresh an expired ID token?
- Is the generated code production-ready, or is it merely serve demo purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is there no client secret?

Because this is client side JavaScript and there for uses implicit flow. The Implicit flow is a simplified OAuth flow used by JavaScript apps where the access token was returned immediately without an extra authorization code exchange step.

> This button gets an ID token, but what about a refresh and access token? How could you refresh an expired ID token?

This is again client side JavaScript Implicit flow.  Implicit flow does not return a  refresh token.   TO get a new id token after it has expired the user will need to login again.

> Is the generated code production-ready, or is it merely serve demo purposes?

Google web identity is in production and what google is currently recommending we used for Client side JavaScript web applications.

Comment: Thanks! I am interested in implementing [authorization code flow with PKCE](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) using the personalized login with Google button. Is that use-case supported?!

Comment: As far as I know Google only supports PKCE for mobile authorization.

Comment: What about authorization code flow without PKCE, but still using the personalized login button?

Comment: Thats the implicit flow it runs now.  This is client side JavaScript you cant do much with it or it would introduce security issues.   Go with server side if you want something more robust.

Comment: Thanks for elaborating on that.